# VBA Create a validation based on the first character of the entry into a cell

Tags: vba, validation, excel, wildcard

Hi I am trying to create a cell validation in Excel through VBA. I am trying to do this through use of a wild card so that the validation in that cell will be based of the first character in the data entry.

Here is the Code I am working with.

```
Dim wild1 as string
wild1 = Cells(11, 7) Like "b*"

With Cells(11, 7).Validation
    .Delete
    .Add Type:=xlValidateCustom, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Formula1:=wild1
End With
```

With the code above I get a validation error every time I try to type something into Cell(11, 7). How would I change this so that the data entry would be valid if the first character in the data entry in that cell starts with a b?

Thanks!

Comment: why not just `Formula1:="=LEFT(G11,1)=""b"""`?

Comment: I was hoping to include a the wildcard after the first character because that is the format it will be coming in from the database I am interfacing this spreadsheet with. Sorry I probably should have mentioned that earlier, Thanks though.

Comment: Really don't understand why you need a wildcard, but if you actually think that you need it - use `Formula1:="=COUNTIF(G11,""b*"")"`

Comment: Thanks! that is closer to what I need. To explain more, in my real spreadsheet I won't be using B* in my code. I have a formula based off another cell on that worksheet that will be pulling in a value from a database, so it won't necessarily always be b* it could be c* or d* etc. In my code though I will just be referencing that formula. Sorry for any confusion I am fairly new to VBA. I appreciate your help though.

Answer (score 0):

This is based on **simoco's** comment.........this event code goes in the worksheet code area:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
 Dim ch As String
    If Intersect(Target, Cells(11, 7)) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    If Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    ch = Left(Target, 1)
    dq = Chr(34)
    With Target.Validation
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateCustom, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
        xlBetween, Formula1:="=left(A1,1)=" & dq & ch & dq
        .IgnoreBlank = True
        .InCellDropdown = True
        .InputTitle = ""
        .ErrorTitle = ""
        .InputMessage = ""
        .ErrorMessage = ""
        .ShowInput = True
        .ShowError = True
    End With
    Application.EnableEvents = False
End Sub
```

and assumes **G7** starts with no validation.  Once a value is entered, the first letter is used in the validation.